# How to find count of each item from Quick books using QBFC

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am importing Items data from quick books to my own project using QBFC.

using code :1  i am able find totla how many items in the quick books.

I Have a requirement to find count each item type from quick books.

But using code : i am not able find how many items in particulat items( ex :Serive)

Code: 1

```
IORItemRet itemRet = default(IORItemRet);
IORItemRetList itemRetList = default(IORItemRetList);
IResponse response = responseSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
if ((response.Detail != null))
{
    itemRetList = (IORItemRetList)response.Detail;
    if ((itemRetList != null))
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= itemRetList.Count - 1; j++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Code: 2

```
IItemServiceRet itemSeriveRet = default(IItemServiceRet);
IItemServiceRetList itemServiceRetList = default(IItemServiceRetList);
IResponse response = responseSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
if ((response.Detail != null))
{
    itemServiceRetList = (IItemServiceRetList)response.Detail;  //Com object Error
    if ((itemServiceRetList  != null))
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= itemServiceRetList.Count - 1; j++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

//Com object Error

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Interop.QBFC10.IItemServiceRetList '. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{C53D1081-9FE4-4569-9181-A9D7E0155907}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Let me now how to find count of each items from Quick books

Comment: What type of request are you sending? ItemQueryRq?

Answer (score 0):

In your code it appears you are checking that response.Detail is not null. But are you also checking the value of response.StatusCode and responseType? If you are getting an error then it seems possible that you are getting a response back that might not implement the IORItemRetList interface. See the code below from the [On Screen Reference](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html).

```
IResponse response = responseList.GetAt(i);
//check the status code of the response, 0=ok, >0 is warning
if (response.StatusCode >= 0)
{
  //the request-specific response is in the details, make sure we have some
  if (response.Detail != null)
  {
    //make sure the response is the type we're expecting
    ENResponseType responseType = (ENResponseType)response.Type.GetValue();
    if (responseType == ENResponseType.rtItemQueryRs)
    {
      //upcast to more specific type here, this is safe because we checked with response.Type check above
      IORItemRetList OR = (IORItemRetList)response.Detail;
      WalkOR(OR);
    }
  }
}
```

Note in the comments from the code above:

> **this is safe because** we checked with response.Type check above

In the SDK Programmers Guide (p.107) it states:

> ...a response object that is a query response contains a Ret list object
>   that contains potentially multiple Ret objects. A response object that
>   is not a query response contains only one Ret object and **no Ret list**.
>   This difference is crucial when it comes to processing the response
>   data.

Once you get the interface checks in place your for loop should work correctly.